# How to detect multiple cliks in a bar in highchart column r shiny plot

Tags: javascript, jquery, r, highcharts, shiny

When I click to disable and immediately after to enable a column, I cannot detect the 2nd event. How can I detect if a column or the legend was disabled and enabled (or vice versa), without any other different event in the middle?

Other question is: it is possible to detect a click on the plot background?

```
library("shiny")
library("highcharter")

ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    column(width = 8, highchartOutput("hcontainer", height = "500px")),
    column(width = 4, textOutput("text"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {      

  a <- data.frame(b = LETTERS[1:10], c = 11:20, d = 21:30, e = 31:40)

  output$hcontainer <- renderHighchart({      

    canvasClickFunction <- JS("function(event) {Shiny.onInputChange('canvasClicked', [this.name, event.point.category]);}")
    legendClickFunction <- JS("function(event) {Shiny.onInputChange('legendClicked', this.name);}")

    highchart() %>% 
      hc_xAxis(categories = a$b) %>% 
      hc_add_serie(name = "c", data = a$c) %>%
      hc_add_serie(name = "d", data = a$d) %>% 
      hc_add_serie(name = "e", data = a$e) %>%
      hc_plotOptions(series = list(stacking = FALSE, events = list(click = canvasClickFunction, legendItemClick = legendClickFunction))) %>%
      hc_chart(type = "column")

  })      

  makeReactiveBinding("outputText")

  observeEvent(input$canvasClicked, {
    outputText <<- paste0("You clicked on series ", input$canvasClicked[1], " and the bar you clicked was from category ", input$canvasClicked[2], ".") 
  })
```

Answer (score 2):

When using click events with Shiny, there is sometimes a need to get the same event with the same value alerted again. Is is inherent to Shiny, that only changes of values will be alerted and reactives only react to changes. 
A simple fix for this is to not only send the value you need, but also a random number or the current time. Something that changes every time.

So a possibility for your legend click, when clicking the same series several times is to change the JS function to

```
Shiny.onInputChange('legendClick', [this.name, Math.random()]);
```

And further in the code use `input$legendClick[1]` to access the series name.

But, in your case, you also want to get the status of the legend item. This of course is a thing that changes from click to click. So if we send that with the name, the input value will always change. So no need for this general advice above. The legend status is stored in the `event` under `event.target.visible`. There, you can see what visibility status the clicked series had, when it was clicked. That means you have the opposite of visibility after you get the click event.

Code below:

```
library("shiny")
library("highcharter")

ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    column(width = 8, highchartOutput("hcontainer", height = "500px")),
    column(width = 4, textOutput("text"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {      

  a <- data.frame(b = LETTERS[1:10], c = 11:20, d = 21:30, e = 31:40)

  output$hcontainer <- renderHighchart({      

    canvasClickFunction <- JS("function(event) {Shiny.onInputChange('canvasClicked', [this.name, event.point.category]);}")
    legendClickFunction <- JS("function(event) {Shiny.onInputChange('legendClicked', [this.name, event.target.visible]);}")

    highchart() %>% 
      hc_xAxis(categories = a$b) %>% 
      hc_add_serie(name = "c", data = a$c) %>%
      hc_add_serie(name = "d", data = a$d) %>% 
      hc_add_serie(name = "e", data = a$e) %>%
      hc_plotOptions(series = list(stacking = FALSE, events = list(click = canvasClickFunction, legendItemClick = legendClickFunction))) %>%
      hc_chart(type = "column")

  })      

  makeReactiveBinding("outputText")

  observeEvent(input$canvasClicked, {
    outputText <<- paste0("You clicked on series ", input$canvasClicked[1], " and the bar you clicked was from category ", input$canvasClicked[2], ".") 
  })

  observeEvent(input$legendClicked, {
    # Visibility of target. When deselecting, the target was visible at the moment of click.
    seriesStatus <- switch(input$legendClicked[2], "FALSE" = "visible", "TRUE" = "invisible")
    outputText <<- paste0("You clicked into the legend and selected series ", input$legendClicked[1], " and this Series is now ", seriesStatus, ".")
  })

  output$text <- renderText({
    outputText      
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Another thing, that might help you to learn about what other things you can do, is to check out the JavaScript console. When running a Shiny app, right click on the display window, press `Inspect` to open the RStudio inspector. There, one of the riders is `Console` where you get all Client side error/warning messages. Now, a useful JavaScript command is `console.log` which prints to this particular console. So, within some of the click functions, try adding the command `console.log(event);` and open the JavaScript console on the next Shiny app startup. The event can be checked out fully, to see which parts of the click events can be useful. (I got the visibility property from just searching there.)

To your second, more broad question: The whole chart has a click event, which can be added to the `hc_chart` function in R. Just like the other click events. More information can be found [here](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.click).